# What to do with questions with no answer but useful comments that link to elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions, answers-as-comments

There are questions on our site (for example [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/can-i-export-to-cpo-file-using-opl) and [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/program-cant-stop-when-using-callback-of-usercut-in-cplex-to-solve-a-branch-and)) with no answer but a useful comment that links to elsewhere. There are lots of discussion on this Meta.SE question: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) or this one: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). But these are mainly about link-only answers.

OTOH, there is this question: [What if I answer a question in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) and this discussion on our own meta: [How can we get people to provide answers instead of comments](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/how-can-we-get-people-to-provide-answers-instead-of-comments). I also remember that [Robert Cartaino](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/11/robert-cartaino) said somewhere (I paraphrase)

> When finally people find this site, we don't want to send them to find their answers elsewhere. Links are good but they should be supplementary.

So, what should we do in these situations? Should we:

- Ask/encourage the commenter to expand their comment into an answer (I get this from combining/summarizing the above)
- Leave the question as is and do nothing and hope that someone else will provide an answer at some point
- Something else

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Shouldn’t this be an answer rather than a comment? (This feels familiar....)

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 That irony... I have no idea why I didn't post as an answer :P

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for the first bullet point (Mark and prubin are very active for the cases you provide). For users that seldom/no longer visit the site, I would copy their comment (if it provides an answer) as a community-wiki answer.

The "link-only" issue can be resolved by adding some exposition; a summary of its content, how it relates to the question etc.